# receiving input from text-field

Tags: java, windows, text, build, printwriter

I'm learning java right now and I want to create a simple program that can grab my text and put it into a txt file. this is my code but nothing is working, it creates the txt file but it doesn't input the actual text from the text- field.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        File file = new File("information.txt");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(500, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(panel);

        JLabel user = new JLabel("user");
        user.setBounds(10, 25, 100, 25);
        panel.add(user);
        JTextField username = new JTextField();
        username.setBounds(100, 25, 300, 25);
        panel.add(username);

        JButton button = new JButton("login");
        button.setBounds(185, 150, 100, 50);
        panel.add(button);
        String name = username.getText();
        panel.setLayout(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        try {
        if (button.getModel().isPressed()){
            file.createNewFile();
        }
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file);
            pw.println(name);
           pw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add an ActionListener to your button.
Then you have to execute the code you want to be executed when pressing on the button within this ActionListener.
You must also get the text from the text box the moment you click the button.

```
  button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    try {
      file.createNewFile();
      PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file);
      pw.println(username.getText());
      pw.close();
    } catch (IOException e2) {
      e2.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi @Jimmy if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.